# Normally distributed data to train CNN network for regression task

Tags: regression, conv-neural-network, normal-distribution

I am training a CNN model for regression task on normally distributed data.

[image: Probability Distribution of data points]

Most of the data points take values between 0.4 and 0.6. Will the network learn the features of datapoints which are less than 0.4 and more than 0.6 which are less represented?

I also don't want to make the distribution uniform as I want the network to learn the distribution of training data.

Answer (score 0):

The model learns whatever you train with. If you train more with some particular type of data points model will learn them well. In your case, the model is more likely to perform well on data points lying in range of 0.4 to 0.6. It is very less likely that model performs better on type of data points lying at the tails of normal curve.

To make the model learn well about the points at the tails of the normal curve, you need to augment the data set to balance it. Other thing you can do is use weighted loss for the data points in the tail region.

Comment: To clarify, My question is not about standardizing the data. I wanted to know if a neural network can learn data points with gaussian distribution when I do regression, as most of the datapoints are clustered around the centre. Will it learn the features of datpoints which are at the tails.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to use weighted loss in keras for continuous values. I know we can specify weightage for particular class when performed for a classification task.

Comment: I don't remember the exact way for it but it can become a different question altogether. I hope my answer helped you. Please mark as accepted if it did.